# ocn-tools won't compile after npm install

Tags: shareandcharge

I'm having a go with ocn-tools to connect to our ocn-node on the test network.

'npm install' pulls in ocn-registry 1.1.0 and does not compile.

'npm ci' (respecting the lock file) pulls in 0.1.0 and does compile. However, I think the network settings are out of date on this version. Is 0.1.0 now too old to try and get working?

Comment: when npm fails, it generates a log file. can you please provide that in order for us to be able to reproduce the error?

Comment: also, sometimes it is due to the node version. Please use node version 14. If this still does not work, you can try to clean up the cache with npm cache clean --force

Comment: Thanks for that. I was using node 12, switching to node 14 got me the equivalent of using 'npm ci' with node 12. Now it compiled but still hung on 'Starting CPO Server'. I am running this locally on a mac with a public ip address forwarded through to port 3000. I solved this by changing the network configuration in node_modules/@shareandcharge/dist/network.js to use https and port 443 and I also had to append NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 as an env var to allow the self signed cert to not be validated.

Comment: @jdh961502 I think the next steps to troubleshooting are to confirm:
1. Is your CPO party successfully registered on the registry?
2. Is your CPO party successfully connected to your OCN-node?

Comment: With regards to the first question, if you have the ocn-registry cli installed, you can check by running `ocn-registry list-parties -n volta` (as you said you're using the Volta test network) or `ocn-registry get-party -c <countryCode> <partyId> -n volta`

Comment: What are the OCPI countryCode and partyID that you are using? Or the wallet address of your party?